# CakePHP 1.3 with muti-type tree

Tags: database, cakephp, internationalization, tree, cakephp-1.3

I am using CakePHP 1.3's TreeBehavior. In one DB table I get all the models records. Every record has a `type` field where the model name is stored. Till now everything is working as a charm. But I get some errors in specific actions. First of all if i do `$this->Article->verify()` I get errors for almost every record:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => index
        [1] => 1
        [2] => missing
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => index
        [1] => 2
        [2] => missing
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => index
        [1] => 3
        [2] => missing
    )
 ....
```

I don't find any difference between the records that has error and those that does not have

I tried `Recover` but still the same. Why am I getting these errors and what do they mean? I have checked the tree data and every field (`parent_id`, `lft`, `rght`) is correct.

**One other issue:**

I wold like to move the records `up` and `down` in the tree. If I set `scope` to the record `type` I move them but all the children records from other types does not move.
My tree is something like this:

```
 Category
    Category
       Category
       Attachment
    Category
       Attachment
    Article
       Attachment
       Attachment
    Article
       Attachment
    Attachment
 Category
 Category
```

If i dont set the `scope` moving a record sometimes does not see the end of the tree and start moving between other record types. How do I set the `scope` to avoid this?

**EDIT:** I have track down the possible problem and probably everything comes from using both `Tree` and `Translate` (which i did not mention) behaviours both in multiple Models using one table. So what happen:

When saving Data for each model it also saves a record in the i18n table with the translation. And when checking with `verify` or `recover`ing the table The Tree behavior only "sees" the posts in the current Model, also giving the "missing index" because not seeing the record from the other models.

Is there any way to fix this, to get it working or to look for other option?

Is there any option to use multiple trees inside one database. So the rght,lft values will be dublicated for every model but there will be no conflict because they will not "know" for each other. Just to use one table and not 10+ with same structure

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. What are you looking for help with? Have you looked at your database and decided you have a 100% valid tree and there's a software issue? Do you not know if your data is valid? What went wrong with `recover()`? Did you try both of its `$mode` settings? http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1356/Data-Integrity.

Comment: Fist question: Why getting the errors for each tree record? And what does it mean? (I have also checked the tree data and every field parent_id,left,right is correct)

Comment: Second Question: How to scope the tree so not to get errors like now: sometimes a record (not at the end) gives error when trying to move, and if no `scope` is set sometimes moving a record between other records (invisibly) from the tree

Answer (score 0):

If your tree metadata is correct then the following should fix any problems which aren't in your own code:

```
$this->Article->recover($mode = 'tree');
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1356/Data-Integrity for more information.

Comment: this does not fix anything but deletes some of the parent_ids, possible issue written at the top post